# SSJS Replace only replaces the first instance of needle

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to replace all instances of `-` in my GUID using SSJS in Marketing Cloud.

```
var job_guid = 'aad2c93e-0e3e-4ec5-8592-f4ff510c1d94';
var stripped_guid = job_guid.replace('-', '');
Write('giud:' + job_guid + '<br>');
Write('stripped_guid:' + stripped_guid + '<br>');
```

The code above only seems to replace the first instance of `-` but not the rest.

> giod:aad2c93e-0e3e-4ec5-8592-f4ff510c1d94
>   stripped_guid:aad2c93e0e3e-4ec5-8592-f4ff510c1d94

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out, need to use the regex modifier `g` to replace all instead of the first instance.

```
var stripped_guid = job_guid.replace(/-/g, '');
```